# Cosa significa "fiottare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola ho letto:

> La prima occhiata, come ogni sera, la diede alla sagoma nera della fabbrica, con la luce che **fiottava** dalle vetrate. Nemmeno la domenica smettevano di lavorare. E con quell'immagine abbagliante negli occhi, e la dolce melodia del film dentro di sé, 
>   scivolò nel sonno.

Non capisco il senso del verbo "fiottare" in questo brano. L'ho cercato nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fiottare/), ma le diverse accezioni fanno referenza all'acqua o a una persona, non alla luce. Mi sapreste spiegare cosa significa che "la luce fiottava dalle vetrate" della fabbrica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La domanda è molto interessante perché in effetti tutti i dizionari riportano per il verbo *fiottare* o per il sostantivo *fiotto* significati legati ai liquidi, all'acqua in particolare. Molti sono invece i casi di testi letterari in cui si dice che la luce fiottava da una finestra (entrando in o uscendo da un luogo). Credo che questo uso si avvicini al significato di "sangue che esce da una ferita", e voglia dare, in modo figurato, il senso della copiosità densa della luce, che esce - nell'esempio riportato - dalle vetrate, come il sangue esce da una ferita.

Un esempio recente: «Il corridoio del quinto piano era silenzioso, deserto. La luce che fiottava dalle finestre si spegneva sulla moquette scura, sul legno spesso e opaco delle porte chiuse» (Romolo Bugaro, *Effetto domino*, del 2015)

Comment: Potresti arricchire la risposta con un paio di altri esempi letterari di luce che fiotta?

Comment: @DaG: Ho aggiunto un esempio recente, italiano, tralasciando le traduzioni (ho trovato un'occorrenza anche in Harry Potter).

Comment: Grazie, @Benedetta !

Comment: La *copiosità densa della luce* meriterebbe un lemma nel De Mauro!

Answer (score 0):

Ciao!

La luce che fiottava non è un termine di uso comune.

Viene utilizzata per indicare qualcosa (per esempio un liquido o in questo caso della luce)

Il senso in generale appare essere come "La luce entrava dalla finestra in modo irregolare e/o a pezzi." Un sinonimo può essere "la luce che filtrava dalla finestra"...